# On my resume, should I list employer company names in English or Spanish?

Tags: resume, job-search, new-job

I'm a New-grad RN from Colombia and of course studied my major in Spanish. Should I put the names of the hopitals I did my practices in, in Spanish or English, or both?

Comment: What did they call themselves?

Comment: Write the official name and then in parentheses include a translation. E.g.  ``xyz @$!%& (XYZ Community Hospital)``

Comment: In many countries, in particular those with more than one official language, may have more than one recognised name. New Zealand would be an example with Māori and English.

Answer (score 7):

I would do it the same way I expand abbreviations by putting it in brackets, for example,.

**NUS (National University of Samoa)**

So if it had two recognised names or even just for clarity.

**The National University of Samoa (Le Iunivesite Aoao o Samoa)** or vice versa if the primary language was Samoan.

This is the conventional method, so best to use since everyone understands it.

Disclaimer: I did not study at the NUS it's just an example, and I in no way imply that hiring someone from there is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Some institutions have also an international title (the one I graduated from is called "Athens University of Economics and Business") in that case use that.
If the institution has only a Spanish name use that. Expecting the reader not to know it provide a short description on what it is and what it does.

My take from my CV and those of friends that I have edited is to use the name with which someone can do an Internet search and locate the institution. Do not forget to add a link to institution's site if this exists (again Eng. version of the site if applicable, local otherwise).

Comment: While I think your answer is generally correct, I've never heard of including a link in a resume.

Comment: @DavidK, you do if you're publishing it electronically.

Comment: I believe it can help a "local" person to validate that the institution abroad first of all... exists and what it is about with a little bit of less effort. You got me thinking though @DavidK if I should remove it from my CV in future revisions.

Comment: @DavidK I provide links in my digital resume if they're relevant. Potential employers are going to search for certain things anyhow (like my LinkedIn page), and by making it easier for them to find it shows I'm not worried about what they will read there and makes sure that they find the correct site.

Comment: @DavidK this conversation perhaps belongs on another question, but I have seen links on paper resumes. It's especially common for hotels and restaurants whose web sites can be hard to find, and which vary wildly in the kind of work they need from someone with a given job title (eg chef.)

Comment: @KateGregory Done! http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/63812/when-to-include-links-in-a-resume