# When to include links in a resume

Tags: resume, websites

My comment in [another answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/63809/16983) sparked a conversation, so I decided to turn it into a question.

When, if ever, is it appropriate to include a link in a resume? In particular I'm curious about links to former employer's websites, but I'm interested in hearing about other purposes as well.

I have never seen it done before and have always thought that printed URLs look clunky and unprofessional. Other people obviously have used them before and find them useful.

Does it matter if the resume is printed or electronic? If someone is going to include a link, how should it be done (hyperlink, tinyurl, full URL, etc.)?

Comment: If someone gets ahold of your resume in five years, will the link still work?

Comment: it would depend on what the link is to as well

Comment: @StevenBurnap In 5 year's time, will you *care* if an out of date resume has broken links?

Comment: I put a QRCode with my contact vcard information next to my (human readable) contact info in my resume, so it is easy for people to just point their phones into it and have me added as a contact. Consider adding one (or more, but beware of a possible visual polution) qrcode with the links so one can easily show the code to a machine and make it follow the link, without having to type it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have seen this on paper resumes. If you work in an industry where URLs are nonobvious (hotels and restaurants often don't have web sites, or have weird things buried under some parent company, and search results are drowned out by review and booking sites) then consider doing it even if your resume is not electronic.

Considerations:

- a human needs to type it, so don't include /index.aspx or /contactus/contact.html if the root web site alone will suffice
- a human may be suspicious about going to random web sites, so don't use a bitly or the like. Ideally someone just reading the link can verify that it is probably what you say it is because they see the company name in it
- if you have your own web site, repeat all the links there and include that link as well as the raw ones

Don't assume people go to the links because you provide them. Include vital information (what you did; something about the employer such as "5 star hotel in downtown Toronto" or "busy accounting practice" or "nationally-known legal firm") in the description, just as you would without the link. The idea is that if someone wants to really drill in (you say that restaurant is fine dining, but what was on their menu? You say that law firm was known for its defense of celebrities, but let's see some press coverage) as part of a screening process, they can. The confidence you project by including this information is non-trivial, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that any URI will have to be retyped by a human. Keep them visible and keep them short. Tiny may be a bit too short.

Better, perhaps: provide Uri of an online version of your resume with links, and say you've done so and where.

Comment: This is the best answer. Links won't matter until someone (or some software) decides your resume is worthy of a second look. Managers are unlikely to follow any reference to external content, though, so your resume needs to stand on its own with the external content. The link to your online resume/portfolio is the only thing someone would ever look at, but only after they've decided they're very interested in you.

Comment: goo.gl solves the problem, the person who is going to read it and type it will kind of trust it just because it has google on it

Comment: @KentAnderson - I think Socrates' answer gives some exceptions where someone may want to look at previous work or some sort of portfolio.

Answer (score 1):

> When, if ever, is it appropriate to include a link in a resume?

It's very appropriate if you are in a field where having a portfolio is important. I also think it would be appropriate if the name is useful when discussing your work experience. Like, "Contributed on development of expedia.com". Essentially, anything that supports your application.

> Does it matter if the resume is printed or electronic?

Seems like hiring managers print out resumes anyway, so I'm not sure it makes a difference. I'd keep the information for all resumes consistent, since you don't know what they will do with it when it gets to their office.

> If someone is going to include a link, how should it be done
>   (hyperlink, tinurl, full URL, etc.)?

I think most people are used to websites that don't use "http://" or "www" - domain.com or location.domain.com are pretty common these days. I wouldn't use a tinyurl because it's not easy to remember. In my case, I have the URL to my portfolio at the top of the page, near my name and right under my email address.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with keshlam, it is good to make it easy to type.

The major question is whether it is of significant important. The thing to realize about a URL is that it is gibberish unless the person goes to the web site. Gibberish is bad. So, basically if there is a high probability the person would visit the site, then it is good, but if the link is just "ancillary" information, then it is bad, because it could just amount to gibberish.

Cases where I would consider an URL relevant and useful:

- designer or artist showing examples of their work
- programmer link to their example source code
- writer link to the text of their published work
- TV producer or director link to YouTube video of their work